# Event: "archived" vs. "filed" vs. "shelved"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms, past-participles

I'm coding a database that has an Events table with a status field. When an event's date has not yet passed, the status is *Published*.

I would like to use a term to mean that the date of the event has passed, something like *Archived/Filed/Shelved*. Which is the correct way to express it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming things in a database.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [expired](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expire):

> (of a document, authorization, or agreement) come to the end of the period of validity

Answer (score 0):

The differences among the words archived, filed, and shelved seem to me a matter of degree and associated with information, a project, or something similar.  If something is "filed," then you can still retrieve it.  "Archived" is filed, but may not be as easily retrieved--that is, it may be stored in another format (compressed data, for instance) or, if hard copy, may be in a warehouse somewhere.  "Shelved" in the movie industry used to be used to refer to a project that had been abandoned and put on hold indefinitely, not likely to be recovered.

Since you're coding and using language to refer to a date of an event that has passed, I think "shelved" comes closest.